# if > 3 selected choices are the same php

Tags: php, comparison, selectedvalue

I have tried to figure this out but cannot get to the bottom of it so am kindly asking for your assistance please. The best way I can explain is with an example.

Let's say you have 6 select boxes, where the user chooses items from them out of a list, once submitted the values will be sent via "GET" and display results on a screen.

How would I go about checking if 3 or more of the 6 selected choices are the same please? I know how to obtain the selected values from GET, but not how to check if 3 or more are the same choice.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Regards

```
<select class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
            <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
<select class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
            <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
<select class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
            <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
<select class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
            <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
<select class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
            <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
<select class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
            <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
            <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
        </select>
```

Comment: With `array_count_values` I suppose

Comment: Are you passing them to GET as an array or are they individual GET variables with different names?  Posting your code would help.

Comment: How can a user select the same thing multiple times to begin with?

Comment: @apokryfos, you can have something like: `<select name='foo'><option value='value_one'/></select><select name='bar'><option value='value_one'/></select>`

Comment: It's difficult to post the code as it isn't written yet, I have been debating on how to do it prior to writing for fears it cannot be done!

Comment: I suppose you need to create one select box with `multiple` attribute.

Comment: Why don't you use a multi select?  Is that viable? Or are the questions different?

Comment: That's not the same thing, that's `$_REQUEST["foo"] == $_REQUEST["bar"]` Same values different keys/names.

Comment: There are 6 select boxes, each will be passed to GET with different names. Unable to use multi-select as there are other values involved too, but I only need to compare the 6 select choices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is what @u_mulder sugggested in the first place: `array_count_values` on your request subset.

However you first must give names to your selects e.g.

```
<select name='select[]' class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
        <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
    </select>
<select name='select[]' class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
        <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
    </select>
<select name='select[]' class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
        <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
    </select>
<select name='select[]' class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
        <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
    </select>
<select name='select[]' class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
        <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
    </select>
<select name='select[]' class="form-control">
        <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Select Choice</option>
        <option value="choice1" >Choice 1</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 2</option>
        <option value="choice1">Choice 3</option>
    </select>
```

(This feels like it could have been done in a loop)

Collect the list of the names e.g.

Check how many times each was selected:

```
if (max(array_count_values($_GET['select'])) >= 3) { 
  /* 3 of the same value selected */
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Unsure as to why the question was down-voted as I haven't found anything similar on SO and I have tried to research it myself, but never knew about array_count_values

Comment: @DisplayName Not sure. Probably because it wasn't 100% clear from the start someone just looked at it, downvoted because of that issue and then left. It does happen sometimes.

Comment: Very true. Thanks for your reply